# Azure WebApp non "www" mapping

Tags: azure, dns

Navigated to Azure WebApp Domain Mappings and added `turnik.city` in addition to `www.turnik.city`.

So "`turnik.city`" cat not be resolved, but "`www.turnik.city`" works fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an A record for the root of your zone (i.e. `@`).

1. Go to your Azure DNS zone
2. Click "+ Record set"
3. Specify:

   - Name: `'@'`
   - Type: `A`
   - Alias record set: *Yes*
   - Alias type: *Azure resource* (then select your Azure AppService or Website)
   - Retain the default 1 hour (3600s) TTL.
4. Click OK
5. Wait a few minutes, then try resolving your names using `dig` or `nslookup` (but configured to *not* use your local or network's DNS cache).

[image]

---

- Also, consider changing your `www` record from a `CNAME` to an `A`
  Azure Alias record. This is preferable [because `CNAME` records require clients to complete two requests (or more) to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748584/are-cnames-slow), which is slower than an `A` record that resolves immediately.